# Micropython - how to create a type in C that inherits another type also defined in C?

Tags: python, c, micropython

How do I create a new Python type in C that inherits another Python type also defined in C?

The behavior should be like this:

```
# TypeA defined in C, has members called a1, a2, ...
a = TypeA()
# TypeB defined in C, has members called b1, b2, ...
# ... and inherits TypeA 
b = TypeB()

# valid because TypeB inherits TypeA
print(b.a1())
# invalid because TypeA does NOT inherit TypeB
print(a.b1())
```

**This is for [Micropython](https://github.com/micropython/micropython). I will only accept a CPython answer if it helps answer the question for Micropython.**

Comment: Too broad???? `Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.`

Comment: What is not specific enough about this?

Comment: Just a thought, you can let C side handle the inheritance if your hierarchy is not very complicated, and take advantage of Python's duck typing. More specifically, maintain inheritance with a tree or lookup table in C, do type checking and cast in C and call methods if valid, everything will essentially be invisible to Python.

Comment: Not sure how can be done but what I once did, was to create structure `TypeB` with a member of type `TypeA`. Thus I could do something like `b.memberA.a1()`

Comment: @PhoenixBlue that’s not acceptable because the syntax would be different from inheritance occurring solely within `.py`. There should be no difference between inheritance in C and inheritance in `.py` code.

Answer (score 1):

As of MicroPython 1.9.4, inheritance on types defined in C is not supported for efficiency reasons. Aka, we were able to go a long way without it. Yes, recently, usecases for that appear more and more often, so it's going to be implemented eventually.